# Finding limits of specific functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying for a qualifying exam and a couple of questions on the study guide I was given are giving me serious trouble. I've been working on the below limits for a couple of days and have gotten nowhere useful. Tests used include the Divergence Test (inconclusive), the Ratio Test (unable to get somewhere useful), the Comparison Test (the most likely to work, in my opinion), and the Root Test (inconclusive). Suggestions about either a different test the will be helpful or a specific series that I can use for the Comparison Test would be helpful

1. $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{k} - 1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)^k$
2. $\frac{1}{ln(2)} + \frac{1}{ln(3)} + \frac{1}{ln(4)} - \frac{1}{ln(5)} - \frac{1}{ln(6)} - \frac{1}{ln(7)}...$

For the first series, I suspect that that the Comparison Test is going to be the test that works, but I can't find a good series to compare to. For the second series, if sort of defies being written in summation form, and so the Ration Test and the Root Test are pretty difficult, if not impossible, to apply. Additionally, the Comparison Test is difficult to use because the immediately obvious series to compare to is $\frac{1}{log(n)}$, which is larger but divergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For number 1, use

$$ \left(\frac{\sqrt k-1}{\sqrt k}\right)^k = \left(1-\frac{\sqrt k}{k}\right)^k \sim e^{-1/2}e^{-\sqrt{k}}$$

To compute this, $$k\log(1-1/\sqrt k)+\sqrt k = k\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt k}-\frac{1}{2k}+o(1/k)\right)+\sqrt k = -1/2+o(1)$$, as $k\to \infty$.

Conclude using $\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt x} < \infty$.

For number 2,
use Dirichlet test, which says $\sum a_nb_n \in \mathbb C$ if $a_n\downarrow 0$ and the partial sums of $\sum b_n$ are bounded. Here, $a_n \in \mathbb R$ and $b_n \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was very helpful, I think I've got the answers fully worked out now.